# ASP.NET Razor Dropdown Selection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have list of string and i have a selected item among those strings.
Controller:

```
ViewBag.GroupName = new SelectList(Names, Names.Find(s=>s==Place.GroupName));
```

View:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupName, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.GroupName)
```

But the selection on the view is always the first item in the list which is not as expected.
What could be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the first parameter you pass to the `Html.DropDownListFor` is set to the value of the `SelectListItem` that should currently be selected.  If the value of it doesn't match any values in the DropDownList, it won't set any item as selected.

In your case, you need to make sure that `model.GroupName` is set to the value of the SelectListItem that should currently be selected.

**Example:**

*.cs:*

```
class myViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue = "3";
    public List<SelectListItem> ListItems = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "List Item 1", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "List Item 2", Value = "2"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "List Item 3", Value = "3"}
        };
}
```

*.cshtml:*

```
@model myViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, Model.ListItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your list like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupName, (IEnumerable<SelectList>)ViewBag.GroupName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide to the SelectList information about Text/Value as well. I suppose that Names is a string list, so you should do something like this:

Create a SelectListItem list from `Names`:

```
ViewBag.GroupName = (from s in Names
                     select new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Selected = s == Place.GroupName, 
                         Text = s,
                         Value = s
                     }).ToList();
```

Then use it in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("GroupName") /*Will get from the ViewBag the list named GroupName*/
```